# How to hide some members of an object to a function while visible to another function?

Tags: oop

I usually use C programming language. Something is inconvenient for me in OO programming. I want the visibility of members in an object to depend on functions' requirement.  Say,

```
class Aclass{
 int i;
 float x;
} A;
```

For function

```
float f(Aclass &A) {
  cout<<"A.x="<< x <<endl;
}
```

I want actually only x is visible to f.

But for function

```
float I(Aclass &A) {
  cout<<"A.i="<< A.i <<endl;
}
```

I want only i is visible to I.

In more realistic situation, an object has a lot of members.  How could I make different part of members visible to different functions?

Comment: I think you mean **C++**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In more realistic situation, an object has a lot of members.

Sounds like that object needs to be decomposed into multiple objects.

> How could I make different part of members visible to different functions?

By refactoring the functionality into separate objects.  If an object is doing so many things that you're finding it difficult to isolate one responsibility of that object from another, then that object is doing *too many things*.

In general, favor many small and simple objects over few large and complex ones.  Keep concerns separated and dependencies isolated.  What you're describing is a classic example of not separating the concerns properly.  If function `A()` shouldn't know about member `i` then they are two separate concerns which don't belong on the same object.

Take a look at the [S.O.L.I.D. Principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) for some general guidelines on isolating dependencies and separating concerns.